# why combo box color change to black (from white initially) for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have below code for combobox in WPF XAML,

```
<ComboBox Background="White">
   <ComboBox.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="White" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
   </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Initially the combobox is showing white background, but after selecting an item from combobox, the background color turns to black like this, what could be the reason? please suggest
[image]

Comment: we observe that this behavior only with Server (2008, 2012) machines, Window 7 perfectly file. Any suggstion

Comment: Well the obvious part should be the `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black" />`. When do you expect a combobox item to be highlighted? I'd say, after the first selection.